# How to pass a variable from one controller to a another with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, controller

To begin with the user selects a value from the dropdown list which stores the selected value in a variable called `$SetNumber` which is located in `ControllerOne`. Once the user selects from the dropdown as you cans see the form action is `/Update` which is used to retrieve and redirect the data to `ControllerTwo`

```html
<form method="POST" action="/Update">
    @csrf 
    <select name="Match" id="Match" onchange="this.form.submit()">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

`ControllerOne` contains an `empty` variable, which defines the variable `$SetNumber`. `ControllerOne`:

```
class ControllerOne extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $SetNumber = "";
    }


    public function update(Request $request)
    {
         $SetNumber = $request->Match;

         return redirect()->action('ControllerTwo@index', ['SetNumber' => $SetNumber]);
    }   
}



class ControllerTwo extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        echo $SetNumber;

        return view('pages.viewpage')->with('SetNumber', $SetNumber);
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I try to echo `$SetNumber` within my controller and return it to my view , prompts me with this error:

> Undefined variable: SetNumber.

how could I do this better?

i am new to laravel and web dev.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameters sent with the redirect function are added to the query string of the generated url. So if you want to access them in the other controllers function, you have to get the value from the request object.

```
class ControllerTwo extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $SetNumber = request()->get('SetNumber');
        return view('pages.spotifyApi')->with('SetNumber', $SetNumber);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks , it worked . Great stuff. I will accept this answer when it allows me

Comment: Glad I could help. consider marking this as the answer to your question so other users might find this as well.